# (C++) Incrementing via Pointer, or: Why is this not working? Pointer->int = Pointer->int+1;

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning some C++ but obviously my brain is still in Java-Mode.

I try to increment an integer variable which is a class variable of another class, to which I have got a pointer as member variable in my active class.

So the basic structure:

```
class A{
public:
int i=0;
}

class B{
public:
A* a;
void incrementA();
}

void incrementA(){
a->i=a->i+1;
}
```

For some reason it still returns 0, while:

```
a->i=1;
```

returns 1.

Is there some kind of mechanism that prevents me from accessing variables via pointers?

Comment: Have you initialized `a`?

Comment: Please post your entire testbench code

Comment: yes, a is initialized, I came across the problem in a rather big code structure, should this basically be possible and the problem has to be another part of my code? But the key elements are not any different as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void incrementA(){
a->i=a->i+1;
}
```

this function doesnt belong to class `B`

you are just defining a standalone function, thats now how you define a member function outside the class.

you should define it like this:

```
void B::incrementA()
{
  //body
}
```

> while a->i=1; returns 1.

that is because you are assigning it to 1

the implementation of your `incrementA` is correct in both semantic and syntax.

```
`a->i+=1;`
```

will also do.

To fix this:

**the creator of thread said:**

Hey everyone, sorry for bothering you, i finally found the problem: In the destructor of B i decrement a->i, and I didnt know that emplace_back() uses the destructor to remove the buffered object :(

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot the B:: in the code snippet above, it is a member function, but thanks for pointing out! Still, I cant increment by +=1, ++ or =i+1, while I can set total values. I really dont know what other parts of the code should possibly interact/avoid with that simple function.

Comment: @PatSch: Don't type your code from memory. Copy and paste it, otherwise you waste everyone's time.

Comment: i see in the comments you initialized your a, let me test it. sec

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for bothering you, i finally found the problem: In the destructor of B i decrement a->i, and I didnt know that emplace_back() uses the destructor to remove the buffered object :(

Comment: how can you know if the `i` is 0 if b is already destructed XD, btw congrats.